# How to display About screen and skip back button with webview

Tags: android

I'm making an application that has a menu with the navigation view and webview. One of the menu item is About, how to display the contents About in the small size of the screen that consist of image and text about the application and developer.

And if after I choose the About menu and then select another menu, if I click the back button, I don't want it to re-display the About screen but back to previous content before I click About. Thanks.

This is my activity code

```
package com.example.intaportalapp;

import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");

        myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                //Check clicked item and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {


                    //Populating main content using webview on the basis of selected menu item
                    case R.id.home: {
                        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
                        return true;
                    }
                    case R.id.portal: {
                        myWebView.loadUrl("http://portal.example.com");
                        return true;
                    }
                    case R.id.ess: {
                        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.humanenergy.com");
                        return true;
                    }
                    case R.id.about: {
                        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about/index.html");
                        return true;
                    }
                    case R.id.exit: {
                        finish();

                    }
                    default: {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

            }
        });


        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.close, R.string.open) {


            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered when the drawer closes
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered when the drawer will open
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            myWebView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack(); // Go to previous page
            return true;
        }
        // Use this as else part
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have made my app with fragment, but got an error

Answer (score 0):

Use `Fragments` for each menu item.

```
Fragment fragment = MenuItem.newInstance(null);
                        FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        trans.replace(FRAGMENT_PLACE_RESOURCES, fragment);
                        trans.addToBackStack("profile");
                        trans.commit();
```

use the `addToBackStack` to go back to previous menu item.Also you can resize the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In the android manifest add "parent activity" to the about activity. This automatically puts a back button in the top left of the screen and the the button or any back command will return to which ever activity you declared the parent.